# react-native init hangs/stalls with no error

Tags: react-native, scaffolding

New to react, working through a udemy tutorial on a Mac. Installed node ok but when I go to start a project

> react-native init projectname

terminal output:

> This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/myuserid/projects/projectname
>   Installing react-native package from npm...

and it just "hangs" there... seemingly frozen or chugging along. When I check Monitor it looks like Terminal is using 0% CPU. There is no indication (backslash flipping or otherwise) that it is processing.

Inside the projectname directory is a "package.json" file and a "node_modules" file with a bunch of subfiles.

I saw this post with a similar problem (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2806), but doesn't look like there is a remedy. Is there any way to speed this up? How can I tell if it has stalled forever? Will this happen during every project init I do?

I'm not in China... I have fast internet... and I'm using NPM 3.3.12

Thank you!

Comment: Try running via `react-native init projectname --verbose` to confirm that something goes wrong. It is usual that the init command takes very long.

Comment: Thanks, @purii. Not sure if the '--verbose' tag jarred something or it was simply the nth time quitting and redoing the command... but now it goes through.  Doesn't seem like the --verbose itself should change anything and I'd love to know the real reason, but glad it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - 3 projects in a row now that init stalls unless I use '--verbose'. Seems like something must be amiss but for those looking for a possible solution, this seems to maneuver around whatever short-circuit is happening.

Comment: I had the same issue recently and solved it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821692/react-native-init-hanging

Comment: I am also encountered the same and searched the solution. But after 5 minutes it started initiating the project.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue , and  i found the 1st comment on the question is useful .

Indeed , If no error, it means that it takes time to download dependencies.

You can track downloading  by adding `--verbose`  :

```
react-native init projectname --verbose
```

You will spend a long period to reach 50% of downloading.

---

Nevertheless, you might face the following error :

> npm WARN react-native@0.34.0 requires a peer of react@~15.3.1 but none
>   was installed.  npm verb exit [ 0, true ]

If so , check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719506/react-native0-26-3-requires-a-peer-of-react15-0-2-but-none-was-installed) .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using an existing (empty) directory as App name
It worked as soon as I changed the App name to something new