# React-native@0.26.3 requires a peer of react@15.0.2 but none was installed

Tags: ios, node.js, npm, react-native

I am trying to set up for the react native. but whenever I update files it gives m error

```
    enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'React Native/package.json'
npm WARN react-native@0.26.3 requires a peer of react@15.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN React Native No description
npm WARN React Native No repository field.
npm WARN React Native No README data
npm WARN React Native No license field.
   MacBook-Pro:React Native$ npm info react dist-tags.latest
```

Please let me know how can I fix.

Answer (score 12):

Installing react should fix the error

```
npm install react --save
```

Also, you may try upgrading your `react-native` install. `react-native` is as `v0.30.0` now

```
npm update react-native
```

Answer (score 3):

In my specific case I was running `npm install` in the wrong directory. I thought I was in my project directory but was one level higher. This meant `react` was missing from installed packages (because there were none) and thus gave this error.

Answer (score 0):

Some steps that worked for me:

```
1. watchman watch-del-all
2. rm -rf node_modules
3. npm install react@15.0.2 --save
4. npm install react@15.1.0 --save
5. npm install
6. rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
7. npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the project I am working on requires a specific version of React. Since it was older than the current release, doing an install/update would still cause the error.

In order to fix the problem, I had to check the `package.json` of the project and install the exact version allowed by the dependency definition. In the OP's case, a

```
npm install react@15.0.2
```

should fix the problem by installing the exact version of the React module that react-native requires.

Verify that the condition was resolved by doing a `npm list` to see if there are any other unmet peer dependencies.